# How do we know a neuron is activated when we use activation function

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, activation-function

I need clarification on when exactly do we say an activation function is activated. The job of activation function is to introduce non-linearity, right. Is it just scaling a given input to confined range?

Comment: Yes, it "activates" the neuron if the input of neuron makes the output to be in a confined range. Simply, by using activation functions, you filter the neurons and activate (use) only the ones whom output falls in a specific range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need clarification on when exactly do we say an activation function is activated.

We don't.  This is not a Boolean thing, to be "active" or "inactive".  You may be thinking in terms of whether a neuron fires (sends an electrical signal through its axon).

Perceptrons (the "neurons" of a software neural network) do not necessarily work this way.  A couple of the activation functions *do* have hard binary signals, (-1 vs 1, or 0 vs 1), but most are continuous functions.

Instead, think of it as an "attention function", an evaluation of "how excited should this neuron get in response to the input?"  For instance, ReLU (`y = max(x, 0)`) translates as "If this is boring, I don't care *how* boring it is; call it a 0 and move on."  `Sigmoid` and `tanh` are more discriminating:

- below -2 ......... forget it
- -2 through 2 ... yes, let's pay attention to the pro's and con's
- above 2 .......... I got the idea -- this is extremely cool ... don't care about the rest of your sales pitch, you already got an A+.

Activation functions are a sort of normalization or scaling filter.  They help the next layer effectively focus on discriminating among undecided cases; a good activation function usually has a useful gradient (say, around 1.0) in the middle range ("the model isn't sure") of its inputs.  They keep a wildly excited input (say +1000) from dominating the next layer's "conversation".

Comment: An output of 1000 would have a disproportionately large effect on the next layer, compared with "normal" values, say, in the range 0-1.  A difference of 0.5 in another input signal would get lost against the +1000 element.

Answer (score 0):

In artificial neural networks, the activation function of a node defines the output of that node given an input or set of inputs. A standard computer chip circuit can be seen as a digital network of activation functions that can be "ON" (1) or "OFF" (0), depending on input.

it depends on what activation function you are talking about. but in general they are used to make the output results clearer in regression or to scale the input to make it easier to choose between them in classification.

References:

- https://medium.com/the-theory-of-everything/understanding-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-9491262884e0
- https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-neural-networks-1cbd9f8d91d6